# Merge two different array data in one array php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I want to merge two different array data in one array, but i'm confuse how to use `array_push` in this case.

this is example of my data input:

```
["author"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "John"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "Doe"
  }
["title"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "book a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "book b"
  }
```

And the result in one array that i mean, like this:

```
["books"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0] =>
        array(2) {
          ["author"]=>
          string(1) "John"
          ["title"]=>
          string(1) "book a"
        }
        [1] =>
        array(2) {
          ["author"]=>
          string(1) "Doe"
          ["title"]=>
          string(1) "book b"
        }
      }
```

I already try using this way but it just return 1 from each array:

```
$data['books'] = [];

      array_push($data['books'], [
        'author' => $data['author'],
        'title' => $data['title']
      ]);

if (isset($data['books'])) {
  foreach ($data['books'] as $k => $v) {
    $data['books'][$k]['author'] = (int)$v['author'];
    $data['books'][$k]['title'] = (int)$v['title'];
  }
}

result:

["books"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["author"]=>
      int(1)
      ["title"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
```

Comment: "confused" means what exactly? Show your effort, and explain where you got stuck in the code.

Comment: Where are you stuck at? What have you tried? What exactly are you confused about? `array_push($arr, $val);` = `$arr[] = $val;` . They are the same. Both add an element to an array.

Comment: How do you construct the first array?  That's what you want to change to get the second one instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to transpose your arrays with the keys in mind.

```
function transpose(array $arr){
  $transArr = [];
  foreach($arr as $keyRow => $subArr) {
    foreach($subArr as $keyCol => $value) {
      $transArr[$keyCol][$keyRow] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $transArr;
}
```

This function can be used universally for similar problems. The function comes from [this class](https://github.com/jspit-de/tableArray).

How to use:

```
$input = [
  "author"=> ["John","Doe"],
  "title" => ["book a","book b"],
];

$books = transpose($input);

echo '<pre>';
var_export($books);
```

Or if you want to use the class:

```
$books = tableArray::create($input)
  ->transpose()
  ->fetchAll()
;
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'author' => 'John',
    'title' => 'book a',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'author' => 'Doe',
    'title' => 'book b',
  ),
)
```

If "author" and "title" exist as two arrays, $ input must first be created like this:

```
$input = ['author' => $arrayAuthor, 'title' => $arrayTitle];
```

Comment: thanks to answer my question :") actually it just need to create 1 var array empty then put it when looping each data huhuhu